# Semantic UI Dropdown - Cannot press enter to go to links in dropdown list

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

I'm working on a keyboard-accessible top navigation bar using Semantic UI, but I can't use the Enter/Return key to access the links in the drop-down menus, even when the focus is on the link. I created a blank [JS Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/hh3k3ow4/) to demonstrate. I'm also using [Chrome Vox](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromevox/kgejglhpjiefppelpmljglcjbhoiplfn?hl=en) as a screen reader, so that I know where the current focus is.

Here's the code:

```
<div class="ui menu">
    <a class="item" href="https://www.google.com">Google 1</a>
    <div class="ui dropdown link item">
        <a href="#">
            <span>Google 2</span>
            <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="menu">
            <a class="item" href="https://www.google.com">Google 2.1</a>
            <a class="item" href="https://www.google.com">Google 2.2</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript setup:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
});
```

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Such functionality doesn't appear to be part of the semantic UI.

This is as close as I've gotten; any use to you?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
    $('div.item').keyup(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            document.location = $(this).find('a.item.selected').attr('href')
        }
    });
    var href = undefined;
    $('div.item a.item').hover(function() {
        href = $(this).attr('href');
    }, function() {
        href = undefined;
    });
    $(document).keyup(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13 && href) {
            document.location = href;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I just thought as long as it's an anchor tag, pressing Enter when the focus is on the tag will take me to the link specified in the tag, which is the case for all the anchor tags I have worked with. That's a nice JS hack, but I'm still hoping for something more official and less of a hack. But thanks, I'm gonna go with your solution if this is a Semantic UI thing that can't be fixed.

Comment: When I tracked the focused element, it appears that tabbing through the dropdown was focusing the *div.menu* rather than the *anchor* tag. I tried doing this: `.dropdown({onChange(value, text, $choice){ $choice.find('a').focus() })` to force it to select the anchor tag, but it just closed the menu when I tried that. I'm surprised this question hasn't been asked before; this can't be good for accessibility!

Comment: That's interesting. And yeah I know. I opened an issue on their GitHub page about this. Thanks, by the way! Looks like I'll have to add some kind of JS hack like in your answer for now.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to handle the onChange event via a function.
In you function you can include the following line to catch key press, including the enter key.

```
if (['click', 'keydown'].includes(event.type)) { // Code Implementation Here}
```